# Is it possible to combine userRolesHeader with roles defined in realm.properties?

Tags: rundeck

So I'm sending all users through apache with mod_auth_kerb. All users come in with a default userRolesHeader of users.

I'd like to add extra roles for specific accounts, but I'm not seeing a good way to do that. If you could define the users in realm.properties and it would combine with the userRolesHeader, that would be useful.

Is there another way to do this? I don't see how it can be done with apache alone since REMOTE_USER isn't available during if/else logic processing.

#rundeck
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.userNameHeader=X-Forwarded-Uuid
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.userRolesHeader=X-Forwarded-Roles

#apache
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Uuid" %{REMOTE_USER}s
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Roles users

Answer (score 0):

Internally Rundeck gets only one method once, if you configure Rundeck to get the users from the `realm.properties` file, Rundeck seeks the roles from that file. Currently [You can combine methods](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#multiple-authentication-modules) but the user/role in different methods doesn't.